# How to change the firing order of Triggers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, trigger

Realy I rarely use triggers. So I met a problem at first time. I have a lot of tables with triggers (2 or more for every table). I would like to know and change the order of firing triggers for every table. Is it possible to get this information?

**ADDED:**

Here is a good enoght [article on mssqltips](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1409) I have found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [following](http://databases.aspfaq.com/schema-tutorials/schema-how-do-i-show-all-the-triggers-in-a-database.html) statement to list all triggers in each table.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'PRINT ''?'' 
EXEC sp_helptrigger ''?'''
```

Once you find out all the triggers. You can manually change the order using  [sp_settriggerorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

IIRC you can not exactly guarantee the order that triggers (with the same definition of what to react to and when) fire for a given action against a table, for any given number of triggers.

You can though if there are three or less, as you can use [sp_settriggerorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx) to set the first to be first, the last to be last, and the one in the middle to have "undefined" order.

If your triggers are sensitive to the order that are executed in this often indicates that your design is getting more complex than it needs to be (usually due to organic growth) and may benefit from some refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

```
-- List tables with triggers and their firing order.  By Jackson Jarvis.
SELECT [tbl].[name] AS 'Table'
      ,[trg].[name] AS 'Trigger'
      ,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY([trg].[id] ,'ExecIsFirstInsertTrigger')
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
            ELSE 'X'
       END AS 'Insert First'
      ,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY([trg].[id] ,'ExecIsLastInsertTrigger')
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
            ELSE 'X'
       END AS 'Insert Last'
      ,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY([trg].[id] ,'ExecIsFirstUpdateTrigger')
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
            ELSE 'X'
       END AS 'Update First'
      ,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY([trg].[id] ,'ExecIsLastUpdateTrigger')
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
            ELSE 'X'
       END AS 'Update Last'
      ,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY([trg].[id] ,'ExecIsFirstDeleteTrigger')
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
            ELSE 'X'
       END AS 'Delete First'
      ,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY([trg].[id] ,'ExecIsLastDeleteTrigger')
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
            ELSE 'X'
       END AS 'Delete Last'
  FROM            [sysobjects] AS [trg] WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN [sysobjects] AS [tbl] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [trg].[parent_obj] = [tbl].[id]
  WHERE [trg].[TYPE] IN (N'TR')
  ORDER BY
       [tbl].[name] ASC
      ,[trg].[name] ASC
  ;
```